# Ubuntu 18.04 - Suspend Issues

Tags: 18.04, suspend

After a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04, I realize that the sleep mode does not work. When I suspend from the menu button or with the `sudo pm-suspend` command, the screen turns off but the power LED stays on and the fan continues to run. In addition, no keyboard keys or even the power button wake the computer. The only solution is to force the shutdown by pressing the power button.

After reading different posts, I did not find a solution to my problem.

- I do not have a nvidia graphics card.
- The command `cat /sys/power/mem_sleep` tells me that I'm in deep mode (`s2idle shallow [deep]`)
- I tried different kernel versions: 4.18.7, 4.17.14 and 4.15.0-34(=current)

Computer specifications: Samsung NP530U3B with ubuntu 18.04 64bit. It's a core i5 with 4Gb of ram and no graphic card.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Hi, I am getting the exact same problem in a Dell Inspiron 7373, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Same is with my ASUS VivoBook laptop but none of solutions here worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

My boss and I had similar issues with our Dell Venue 11 Pro 7140.  After many releases, Dell eventually discovered an S3 bug relating to pre-5.0 kernels.  They advised 2 things:

1. Update the BIOS to the latest version available, most likely post-November 2018.
2. Upgrade to a 5.0 kernel.

Additionally, we found 2 more things were required:

3. Completely clean your user config (as in, `mv ~/.config ~/.config.old`) as some previous settings in X11 have hung around in upgrade and are incompatible with S3 "freeze" features.
4. a. If using Gnome, change Settings->Power->"When the power button is pressed" from "Nothing" to "Suspend".

   b. If using XFCE, change all "freeze" settings to "suspend" in the Power Manager.

Comment: Hi tudor! Thank you for your advice. I upgraded the kernel to 5.2, I cleaned the .config folder and my power button was already set up properly. Unfortunately nothing works :/ Note: hibernate mode (`pm-hibernate`) works properly.

Comment: How are you on a 5.2 kernel?  The current (stable) as of today is 5.0.0-21.  Are you on mainline by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where suspend would shutdown my machine, but I could not restart it without a hard reboot on the PSU. I resolved it by installing one package:

`sudo apt install uswsusp`

I verified this worked by suspending from the terminal:

`sudo systemctl suspend`

Comment: Hello yellowjacket05,

Thank you for your help unfortunately the installation of the package does not change anything. I waited 5 minutes to be sure but the power led stays on and the fan continues to turn...

Comment: My issue was somewhat different.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo systemctl suspend -i
```

[ edited to -i as I incorrectly put in -l previously]

and I need to unplug all usb ports before doing so else they are lost.
it is, however, unreliable as said above.

also last night it was as you say yours is, blank screen fan running and did not go to sleep until I pressed the space bar. go figure.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/960166)

Comment: It does for me, without that -i  in a terminal I get the following error message."Operation inhibited by "....... reason is "user session inhibited".
Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users.
Alternatively, ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl suspend -i'.
"